# Everything seems to work except placing string in cells

Tags: excel, vba

This code doesn't print `-1` and `0` when it's supposed,
but everything else works fine.

It iterates through both lists: (`Sheet1` and `edi_partnere`)
and exits loops when it's supposed.

**Q: What am I missing: why isn't `cells().value` catching?**

```
Do
    If orgnr1 = "" Then Exit Sub
    Do
        orgnr2 = Sheets("edi_partnere").Cells(j, 1).Value
        If orgnr2 = orgnr1 Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9).Value = "-1"           'not happening
            Exit Do
        ElseIf orgnr2 = "" Then
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9).Value = "0"            'not happening
            Exit Do
        Else: j = j + 1
        End If
    Loop
    i = i + 1
    orgnr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Loop
```

Comment: Did you step through the code to check how the code runs?

Comment: `If orgnr1 = "" Then Exit Sub` When you start the code, does `orgnr1` have any value? If not then the second `Do` will not execute. If you are not setting any value for it then move that line after `orgnr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value` and try again.

Comment: Yep, when stepping through I find the outer loop has run through all its supposed rows, and the inner loop at least once. It turns out I didn't reset the iterator for each inner loop so it ran only once.

Comment: `orgnr1` is set before the first Do, omitted here by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you must reset the variable j, so I add j = 0 in your code.

According to Siddharth Rout if orgnr1 not set then orgnr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value

```
Do
    If orgnr1 = "" Then Exit Sub  
  Do
    orgnr2 = Sheets("edi_partnere").Cells(j, 1).Value       
    If orgnr2 = orgnr1 Then       
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9).Value = "-1"           'not happening
        Exit Do       
    ElseIf orgnr2 = "" Then       
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 9).Value = "0"            'not happening
        Exit Do            
    Else: j = j + 1
    End If           
  Loop   
  j = 0
  i = i + 1   
  orgnr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value
Loop
```

Comment: Btw, I should add that this code uses the wrong iterator for printing 0 and -1 where `i` should be used: `Cells(i, 9).Value = "-1"`. Now it Works Perfect.